Connection Issue on my Web Platform Only on Mobile
I have a web platform where users can log in. On PC, everything works perfectly, but on mobile, once the user logs in, the platform either seems to remain stuck on a loading screen or the user is not actually logged in. I have verified that cookies are correctly configured with attributes httpOnly, sameSite: "none", and secure: true. Additionally, CORS seems to be properly configured. However, after successful login, when the application tries to access the /me resource, a 400 error is returned with the message "Please login to access this resource".
I have also noticed that in the logs, the login process seems to proceed correctly, but something seems to happen after this step.
I wonder if the problem comes from my code or if there is something specific to consider to ensure compatibility with mobile browsers.
Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this issue?
the last one is the problem.
heroku logs `2024-04-26T15:52:32.991417+00:00 app\[web.1\]: A user connected
2024-04-26T15:52:49.927411+00:00 heroku\[router\]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/api/v1/login" host=lastchance1-933ac39139be.herokuapp.com request_id=74718b23-d9db-4b81-83d9-f40c95eaf4a9 fwd="94.109.190.191" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=204 bytes=396 protocol=https
2024-04-26T15:52:50.375420+00:00 app\[web.1\]: loginuser
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539767+00:00 app\[web.1\]: dhhdh {
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539780+00:00 app\[web.1\]:   avatar: {
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539781+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     public_id: 'avatars/wglygyiskmy4bdhyhjre',
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539782+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     url: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dyigkyptj/image/upload/v1711374039/avatars/wglygyiskmy4bdhyhjre.jpg'
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539782+00:00 app\[web.1\]:   },
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539783+00:00 app\[web.1\]:   \_id: new ObjectId('65b8c948b23f77136afd2ef1'),
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539784+00:00 app\[web.1\]:   name: 'Achraf Benali',
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539784+00:00 app\[web.1\]:   email: 'achrafb768@gmail.com',
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539785+00:00 app\[web.1\]:   password: '$2a$10$rGL2q1SAgUOC.X1bonqtruOVwQrC55DIzfsT3i5uy2fACSziCzgEu',
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539797+00:00 app\[web.1\]:   role: 'admin',
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539797+00:00 app\[web.1\]:   isVerified: false,
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539797+00:00 app\[web.1\]:   courses: \[
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539798+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     { \_id: new ObjectId('65cbddffef56810b43f349a9') },
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539798+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     { \_id: new ObjectId('65f4f0dab300cc3570cb513f') },
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539798+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     { \_id: new ObjectId('65f4c07ab1a5b263fde97883') },
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539799+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     { \_id: new ObjectId('65f5a2e72e60a065c84fd9dd') },
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539799+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     { \_id: new ObjectId('65f5d41e2e60a065c84fdb8c') },
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539799+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     { \_id: new ObjectId('65f642fb2e60a065c84fddb0') },
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539800+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     { \_id: new ObjectId('660842576101fa7692823658') },
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539800+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     { \_id: new ObjectId('6625759e931fd573322f3082') },
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539801+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     { \_id: new ObjectId('66266ca8353bf45fd606e685') },
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539801+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     { \_id: new ObjectId('662676a6353bf45fd606e83e') }
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539801+00:00 app\[web.1\]:   \],
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539801+00:00 app\[web.1\]:   createdAt: 2024-01-30T10:02:48.344Z,
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539801+00:00 app\[web.1\]:   updatedAt: 2024-04-25T12:31:26.933Z,
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539802+00:00 app\[web.1\]:   \__v: 14
2024-04-26T15:52:50.539802+00:00 app\[web.1\]: }
2024-04-26T15:52:50.542638+00:00 heroku\[router\]: at=info method=POST path="/api/v1/login" host=lastchance1-933ac39139be.herokuapp.com request_id=ea317a38-1ea1-4deb-b824-83ec3ed885e2 fwd="94.109.190.191" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=168ms status=200 bytes=1945 protocol=https
2024-04-26T15:52:50.761201+00:00 heroku\[router\]: at=info method=GET path="/api/v1/me" host=lastchance1-933ac39139be.herokuapp.com request_id=e7de43d2-bdd7-47f6-af52-d7dad87cfb8c fwd="94.109.190.191" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=400 bytes=415 protocol=https `

It's been a month now, and I've been struggling to solve this issue, but without success. I suspect that the problem lies in the fact that mobile browsers are not sending the cookies as requested, which is why the /me endpoint is not functioning properly. here is my site if you wan tto see the problem with ios my site (in french)
here is my user.route;
import Express from "express";
import { activateUser, deleteUser, getAllUsers, getUserInfo, loginUser, logoutUser, registrationUser, socialAuth, updatePassword, updateProfilePicture, updateUserInfo, updateUserRole } from "../controllers/user.controller";
import { authorizeRoles, isAutheticated } from "../middleware/auth";
const userRouter = Express.Router();

userRouter.post("/registration", registrationUser);

userRouter.post("/activate-user", activateUser);

userRouter.post("/login", loginUser);

userRouter.get("/logout", isAutheticated, logoutUser);

userRouter.get("/me", isAutheticated, getUserInfo);

export default userRouter;


here is my getUserInfo in user.controller.ts:
// update access token
export const updateAccessToken = CatchAsyncError(async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        const refresh_token = req.cookies.refresh_token as string;
        const decoded = jwt.verify(refresh_token, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN as string) as JwtPayload;

        const message = "Could not refresh token";
        if (!decoded) {
            return next(new ErrorHandler(message, 400));
        }
        const session = await redis.get(decoded.id as string);

        if (!session) {
            return next(new ErrorHandler("Please login for access this resources!", 400));
        }

        const user = JSON.parse(session);

        const accessToken = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN as string, {
            expiresIn: "5m",
        });

        const refreshToken = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN as string, {
            expiresIn: "3d",
        });

        req.user = user;

        res.cookie("access_token", accessToken, accessTokenOptions);
        res.cookie("refresh_token", refreshToken, refreshTokenOptions);

        await redis.set(user._id, JSON.stringify(user), "EX", 604800); // 7days

        return next();
    } catch (error: any) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 400));
    }
});

// get user info
export const getUserInfo = CatchAsyncError(async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        const userId = req.user?._id;
        getUserById(userId, res);
    } catch (error: any) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 400));
    }
});

interface ISocialAuthBody {
    email: string;
    name: string;
    avatar: string;
}


here is my auth.ts:
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import { CatchAsyncError } from "./catchAsyncErrors";
import ErrorHandler from "../utils/ErrorHandler";
import jwt, { JwtPayload } from "jsonwebtoken";
import { redis } from "../utils/redis";
import { updateAccessToken } from "../controllers/user.controller";

// authenticated user
export const isAutheticated = CatchAsyncError(async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const access_token = req.cookies.access_token as string;

    if (!access_token) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler("Please login to access this resource", 400));
    }

    const decoded = jwt.decode(access_token) as JwtPayload;

    if (!decoded) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler("access token is not valid", 400));
    }

    // check if the access token is expired
    if (decoded.exp && decoded.exp <= Date.now() / 1000) {
        try {
            await updateAccessToken(req, res, next);
        } catch (error) {
            return next(error);
        }
    } else {
        const user = await redis.get(decoded.id);

        if (!user) {
            return next(new ErrorHandler("Please login to access this resource", 400));
        }

        req.user = JSON.parse(user);

        next();
    }
});

// validate user role
export const authorizeRoles = (...roles: string[]) => {
    return (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        if (!roles.includes(req.user?.role || "")) {
            return next(new ErrorHandler(`Role: ${req.user?.role} is not allowed to access this resource`, 403));
        }
        next();
    };
};


here is my jwt.ts:
require("dotenv").config();
import { Response } from "express";
import { IUser } from "../models/user.model";
import { redis } from "./redis";

interface ITokenOptions {
    expires: Date;
    maxAge: number;
    httpOnly: boolean;
    sameSite: "lax" | "strict" | "none" | undefined;
    secure?: boolean;
}

// parse enviroment variables to integrates with fallback values
const accessTokenExpire = parseInt(process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE || "300", 10);
const refreshTokenExpire = parseInt(process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE || "1200", 10);

// options for cookies
export const accessTokenOptions: ITokenOptions = {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + accessTokenExpire * 60 * 60 * 1000),
    maxAge: accessTokenExpire * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "none",
    secure: true,
};

export const refreshTokenOptions: ITokenOptions = {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + refreshTokenExpire * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
    maxAge: refreshTokenExpire * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "none",
    secure: true,
};

export const sendToken = (user: IUser, statusCode: number, res: Response) => {
    const accessToken = user.signAccessToken();
    const refreshToken = user.signRefreshToken();

    // upload session to redis
    redis.set(user._id, JSON.stringify(user) as any);

    res.cookie("access_token", accessToken, accessTokenOptions);
    res.cookie("refresh_token", refreshToken, refreshTokenOptions);

    res.status(statusCode).json({
        success: true,
        user,
        accessToken,
    });
};


here is my user.services.ts:
import { Response } from "express";
import { redis } from "../utils/redis";
import userModel from "../models/user.model";

// get user by id
export const getUserById = async (id: string, res: Response) => {
    const userJson = await redis.get(id);

    if (userJson) {
        const user = JSON.parse(userJson);
        res.status(201).json({
            success: true,
            user,
        });
    }
};



Use https://axiom.co/ to log more information server-side and check what is happening. This is probably a client-side issue, as you pointed out.

the problem is:
error
:
data
:
{success: false, message: 'Please login to access this resource'}
status
:
400
[[Prototype]]
:
Object
isUnhandledError
:
false
meta
:
{request: Request, response: Response}
[[Prototype]]
:
Object --> but I'm logged that's what I dont understand. The user manages to connect but there is a 400 bug that causes the loading to be buggy and the error to be repeated very quickly. This problem happens especially that on mobile on my pc everything works fine, on IOS it does not work the same bug and android also on some phone.

error
:
data
:
message
:
"Sa marche pas/user pas cree"
success
:
false
[[Prototype]]
:
Object
status
:
400
[[Prototype]]
:
Object
isUnhandledError
:
false
meta
:
request
:
Request {method: 'GET', url: 'https://lastchance1-933ac39139be.herokuapp.com/api/v1/me', headers: Headers, destination: '', referrer: 'about:client', …}
response:
Response
body: (...)
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
type: "cors"
url:"https://lastchance1-933ac39139be.herokuapp.com/api/v1/me"
